# Querying Google Groups

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I've implemented many Google Sheet Add-Ons in my company, utilizing Google Groups for permissions to run these scripts.

For example:

```
function script_permissions() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  var email = user.getEmail();
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("perm_thisscript@domain.com")

  if (group.hasUser(email)) {
    continueWithSript();
  } else {
   throw new Error("You are not authorized to use this report. ");
  }
}
```

Until today, this has been working great with nested groups. At the top level I would have a group, perm_thisscript@domain.com, and then add other Google Groups for the groups of users I want to give access, such as purchasing@domain.com or sales@domain.com. The script would find the users email address within those nested groups and the users could proceed with running the script.

Starting today, the script doesn't seem to recognize the users assigned to a nested group. We are continuing to get the error, "You are not authorized to use this report", as I have coded above.

If I add the user email directly to the perm_thisscript@domain.com group, it works as expected.

What am I missing why this no longer works as it did before today?

Comment: This would be a good question for the Add-ons community:  [Link to Google Developing Add-ons Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)  If it's a bug, you can search the issues list, and if not found, file an issue:  [Apps Script Issues List](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)